# error C2664: 'VariantCopy' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const VARIANT *' to 'VARIANTARG *'

Tags: c++, atl

While using VariantCopy method, I come across the following compile error:

```
error C2664: 'VariantCopy' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const VARIANT *' to 'VARIANTARG *'
```

Is there any way to solve this error? Do I need to include any preprocessor directive or library?

Comment: Hm, and which source code did produce this error?

Comment: ::VariantCopy(&variable1, &variable2); Both parameters are VARIANT

Comment: @MCD So maybe `variable1` is constant?

Comment: The first parameter is not constant, but the second one is.

Comment: Maybe you are missing `#include <oaidl.h>`?

Comment: It's included, very strange error.

Comment: @MCD: Second parameter has to be non-const as well. Or, you need to use `const_cast` to remove the attribute. `VariantCopy` might need to lock variant parts, and for this reason source of the copy operation cannot be const.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of `VariantCopy` used to be

```
HRESULT VariantCopy( 
  VARIANTARG FAR* pvargDest, 
  VARIANTARG FAR* pvargSrc 
);
```

It is strange, but the input parameter is not const, you should be aware of that in your code.

MSDN documentation explains why. The function might modify `pvargSrc`

> If pvargSrc is a VT_DISPATCH or VT_UNKNOWN, AddRef is called to
>   increment the object's reference count.

**Update**

In the most recent SDK, the 2nd parameter became `const`. However, I found this in MFC sources:

```
static HRESULT copy(_Out_ VARIANT* p1, _In_ const VARIANT* p2) 
{
    p1->vt = VT_EMPTY; 
    return VariantCopy(p1, const_cast<VARIANT*>(p2));
}
```

Comment: Seems to be a Windows SDK problem. My version has: WINOLEAUTAPI VariantCopy(__out VARIANTARG * pvargDest, __in const VARIANTARG * pvargSrc); in OleAuto.h

Comment: @MCD: Do you have by a chance several versions of SDK installed?

Comment: I use v7.0 but in Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows there are several versions from 5.0 to 7.0A

Comment: @MCD: Are you sure that the most recent version is included?

Comment: When I check from visual studio, it takes under 7.0.

Comment: with right-click/go to definition. I remember I have changed the version with WindowsSdkVer a while ago to 7.0

Comment: @MCD: You shouldn't rely upon Go to definition. Try to move older versions away to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in different Windows SDKs the methods were different, that's why I had the problem.